He worked in the field during most of the day

He worked in the field during most of the day.

'the day' means 'daytime' or 'the whole day including (some of) night'?

'The day' in such a sentence might mean 'the hours of daylight', or 'the customary working day'. It is unlikely to mean 'the 24 hours starting at midnight'. Common sense tells us that working in a field at night might be difficult (because of the darkness) and also many countries have laws forbidding forcing people to work such long hours.

Thx. Michael. What about the night shift worker? And a police officer asks a witness 'what did he do on that day?' and the witness says "He worked in the field during most of the day." In this case, I think the day means only night hours during which he worked.

Night shift worker in the fields? I've not heard of that and my grandparents had sheep, goats, chickens cows, and even a horse they would look after.   A farmer tends to work in the fields when it is daylight if that is what you want to say then talk about the time he or she leaves the house and what time they return home to rest. Aled worked in the fields from 9.30 am until 5.30 pm. Now, it depends what you mean by "in the field" it could also be the field of medicine, engineering, manufacturing...

The day never means 'the night hours'.

Although as Mari-Lou pointed out there could be other kinds of "field," if this is about working with crops, then I feel like you've proposed so strange a reading that this question would be more answerable if you explain why you think that might be possible.

I agree with the first comment. As a native English speaker, if someone says this to me, I just automatically work out the context. As has been said, day can me 24 hours, or when it is sunlight, or "the working day 9-5" etc. You have to see the context. Here it probably means "during the working day"


He worked in the field during most of the day.

"during most of____" is not truly idiomatic, as this ngram indicates.
The idiomatic "mainstream" preposition for this usage is "for":

He worked in the field for most of the day.

"During" can be used only with expressions that resolve to a duration:

He worked in the field during the day and in his meth lab at night.

But "most of the day" refers to the greater part of the daylight hours or the greater part of the workday. It doesn't refer to a duration of time but to fractional amount of time, a proportion or ratio of sorts.
Consider:

I shop at the chain supermarket most of the time. Sometimes I go to the farmers market.

This would not be correct:

I shop at the corner supermarket during most of the time.

P.S. If there is a semantic shift going on such that during is now being used here and there, now and then, with "most of ________", consider that for many speakers the usage will sound clumsy at best.

You can say what you like, you know. Ludwig Guru and a bunch of publications disagree with you. during most of the [week, month, year, class etc.] is completely idiomatic in English. for is also used, like I said in my answer.

Oh look, the King's English: During most of the day the entrance to Horse Guards is guarded by two mounted sentries. After the duty officer has inspected them at 4:00pm, all personnel, mounted and dismounted, will come off duty for the day. https://www.householddivision.org.uk/king-life-guard

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+most+of+the+day%2Cduring+most+of+the+day&year_start=1975&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2009&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=false

Merriam Webster:
Examples of during in a Sentence
She swims every day during the summer.

We got along well during the trip about my previous jobs.

He worked in the field *during most of the day.*

The fire alarm went off during the ceremony.

It's from MW
Question: What is the day?
The day here means daytime, yes. No night. As in: to work a day shift or schedule. It does not include the night.
during most of the day can be expressed as: for most of the day.
during most of the day, month, year, the hours
during part of the day, month, year, the hours
can both be used with for to. They are idiomatic. But the word time does not work there.
Generally, when a full 24 hours is meant, we don't use day on its own. Just the word day on its own cannot refer to a night shift.

When did he work on Thursday? He worked the night shift.
When did he work on the day of the murder? He worked the night shift. It was not during the day.

Compare: during most of the day [daytime]
during most of the night [nightime]
Ludwig Guru (you have to sign up)
It appears that the strong positive trend in the data began early and continued during most of the day.
1
Princeton University
The precipitation that had stayed focused in the Carolinas during most of the day was now moving northward into Virginia.
2
The Washington Post
We find that while the CA has no effect during most of the day, its effect on the last minutes of trading is dramatic.
3
Journal of Financial Intermediation
Flights leaving for Britain were canceled during most of the day, but air traffic bound for the United States was close to normal, spokesmen for different airlines said.
4
The New York Times
On Thursday, after being tipped off that a group of protesters housed in a local school had gasoline bombs, the police surrounded the school and kept 400 activists penned in during most of the day.
5
The New York Times
Gov. Christine Todd Whitman and several Republican congressmen accompanied him during most of the day, which included a walk down the main street of Freehold, a pep rally at the Burlington County Republican headquarters and a visit to a gated retirement community in Ocean County.
6
The New York Times
However, Mumford continued, The load of pedestrians has likewise become so heavy, not merely at the lunch hour or during Christmas shopping but during most of the day, that the walker is frequently slowed down to the exhausting creep of the car or the bus.
7
The New Yorker
But during most of the day, Zenly doesn't do much.
8
TechCrunch
IM, email, the CrunchGear chatroom and task manager where we administer the site — these are my main methods of social interaction during most of the day.
9
TechCrunch
As a result, the corresponding modelled time series are slightly higher than the corresponding measured time series during most of the day.
10
Earth, Planets and Space
The distillate water produced was noticeably larger at the water mass flow rate of 0.348 kg/h than the other flow rates considered during most of the day.
11
Renewables: Wind, Water, and Solar
On the other hand, the Esb layers on Event W appear with a greater intensity in our simulations, because of the lower E z values during most of the day.
And many more.

I feel like one concession would be that "day" could be reasonably used generically to refer to the calendar date (though "date" is more likely especially the more formal the context), and that enables conversations in which "day" is used before learning that the scope is restricted to night. In your example, the respondent clarifies "it wasn't day," but I feel like that's understood even if not said. E.g. "What day do you fly to Italy?" "The eighth, at 3 am." I feel like that's fine on its own without adding "... so, not day but night."

@AndyBonner I think one covers the major points not every single, itty-bitty thing. What day do fly to Italy> Tomorrow. At night.

I think what I'm getting at is I feel a slight disagreement with your and Michael Harvey's position that "day" is never appropriate for night; I feel that there is a "generic day." In fact, I think the conversation order could reasonably be "My flight to Italy is 3 am." "Really? What day?" But I don't feel strongly about it, and it doesn't seem relevant to the OP's given context, so I'm not inclined to put much effort into defending the notion.

I feel there is a little too much attention drawn on the phrase "during most of the day" as if you were answering a different question. But I agree, the phrase sounds perfectly acceptable in English.

@Mari-LouA Yes, but I did answer the question. In any event, it would be nice if you commenters said something about the answer that claims that "during most of the day" is not idiomatic. That explains why I veeered off course.

Blimey, Lambie. Don't get so defensive. I upvoted the answer because I think all of it (not just most) was good. And... actually... I did say in my comment that I find the phrase perfectly acceptable. So you can upvote it, if you agree :)

@Mari-LouA My defensiveness is about no one backing me up under comments made to me by the other person who answered and  who claims that "during most of the [day, week] etc." is not idiomatic in English. That is why I responded with so many newspaper examples, which made my actual answer less visible. Thanks for upvoting. I will uptick as well.
